# How to add argument to stream buffer c++

Tags: c++, arguments, operators, streambuf

I just want a way to have a function ( or anything else ) which have one standard argument and another one coming from the operator <<.

```
my_comp(argument) << "HelloWorld" ;
```

The goal is to purpose a Logger class that any other class can easily extends and call its unique functionality with a single line of code.

The Logger class mainly use boost/log/ packages, and its unique functionally may be write many time. This is why I want it in a single line.

I do not authorize myself to use the function :

`BOOST_LOG_SEV(argument_boost_dependent, argument_logger_class_dependent) << "something"`

because I do not want any dependency with boost on my interface.

So I'm trying to do something like this :

```
loggit(argument_logger_class_dependent) << "something"
```

and just call `BOOST_LOG_SEV` with boosts arguments in the class implementation

For now I just have a struct that extends std::streambuf so it only work like this : `loggit << "HelloLog"` or by overriding operator () `loggit(severity_level::warning)` but both together do not work.

If anyone know how to add this sweety argument, would be welcome :)

Thanks

Comment: `my_comp(argument) << something` is just another way to write `my_comp(argument).operator<<(something)` So you see that `my_comp()` won't be able to make use of `something`.

Comment: Indeed @JaMiT I'm not from an English-speaker country, it's not such easy to explain.
Well, i already saw code having this structure. And if i can implement it, it will brillantly do what i want to.
If you guys think you need more code to understand what i want to do, tell me

Comment: @Swordfish But if my_comp is a streambuff it can handle the `something` part right ?

Comment: What is `my_comp` supposed to do? Answer @JaMiT s question.

Comment: @Goozzi There is evidence in your update that you are a non-native English speaker, but overall that is a good description. Good job! (The comparison to Boost was a great idea.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```cpp
#include <iostream>

struct foo
{
    int bar;

    foo(int bar) : bar{ bar } {};
    foo& operator<<(std::string baz)
    {
        std::cout << bar << ' ' << baz;
        return *this;
    }
};

int main()
{
    foo(42) << "Hells in the World!\n";
}
```

Makes sense? No? Question answered?

Comment: Didn't though about construct it at each call ! Indeed it solve my problem, TY Swordfish !
But btw, do you think their is a way to do it without construct it every time for performance ?

Comment: Arf for now, it don't fit well cause of construction, it's a InnerClass :/ i'll probably change some stuff, anyway ty.

Comment: @Goozzi I don't see why this will be any slower than a straight function. The constructor is just a function after all. Being on the stack means there is no memory allocation penalty.

Comment: I just thought that construct / destruct at every call was a lot. But i might be wrong,

Answer (score 2):

Slightly improvising on @Swordfish's answer: instead of calling a constructor each time, one can overload the operator() as below:

```
#include <iostream>

struct foo
{
    int bar;

    foo() {};
    foo& operator() (int arg)
    {
        bar = arg;
        return *this;
    }
    foo& operator<<(std::string baz)
    {
        std::cout << bar << ' ' << baz;
        // call BOOST_LOG_SEV with arg and baz
        return *this;
    }
};

int main()
{
    foo logger;
    logger(42) << "Hells in the World!\n"; //prints " 42 Hells in the World!"
    logger(32) << "So is heaven\n";  //prints "32 So is heaven"
}
```

Comment: As simple as that, TY indranil !